# Custom Post Type does not appear in nav_menu

Tags: wordpress

I have several custom Post Types in my template. Now i want to build the menu but they are not appearing.
Here I am initialising a custom Post type:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_subpage_type' );
function create_subpage_type() {
    register_post_type( 'subpage',
        array(
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,

            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Disziplinen' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Disziplin' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'supports'            => array( 'title'),
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'behandlungen'),

        )
    );
}
```

[image: and this is how it looks in the menu administration]

I think in this view should now 'disziplin' appear, shouldn't it?

Thanks for your help.
Cheers

Comment: try clicking on "screen options" in the top / right. Sometimes the boxes are hidden by default.

Comment: oh what a stupid mistake. thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try clicking on "screen options" in the top / right. Sometimes the boxes are hidden by default.

Answer (score 1):

See [this bug](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18950), since you are declaring the post type public as true, there is no need to redeclare `show_in_nav_menus`

Try this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_subpage_type' );

function create_subpage_type() {

  $labels = array(
    'name' => __( 'Disziplinen' ),
    'singular_name' => __( 'Disziplin' )
  );

  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'supports' => array( 'title'),
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'behandlungen')    
  );

  register_post_type( 'subpage', $args);

}
```

Comment: Tried this one before. I was just to stupid to tick the CPT in the screen options :) Thanks anyway